# JS convert JSON object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert a JSON key value object to an Array, but I'm not sure how to get it in the format I need. What I have for the JSON is something similar to below:

```
{
  "01": "yes",
  "02": "yes",
  "03": "no"
}
```

but I need an Array like the one below so I can iterate through it easily:

`["01:yes","02:yes","03:no"]`

or is it possible to iterate through this JSON object while accessing the keys and values easily?

Comment: Possible: Yes. Have you tried to iterate over object using `for..in` and create array from `key:value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

**[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** *returns an `array` of a given object's own `enumerable properties`*

```js
var obj = {
  "01": "yes",
  "02": "yes",
  "03": "no"
};
var op = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b + ':' + obj[b]);
}, []);
console.log(op);
```